# Two ends are occupied by boys and no girls are adjacent.

Tags: combinatorics

I am learning combinatorics from the book [Principles and Techniques in Combinatorics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9810211392).
I am having some trouble understanding why my solution to the following problem is incorrect:

> **Example 1.2.3.** There are 7 boys and 3 girls in a gathering. In how
>   many ways can they be arranged in a row so that
>   (i) the 3 girls form a single block (i.e. there is no boy between any two of
>   the girls)?
>   **(ii) the two end-positions are occupied by boys and no girls are adjacent?**

The second part is what I am having trouble with.

I first arrange two boys in the two extreme positions. There are $P(7,2)$ ways of doing this. Then for the remaining eight positions, I calculate the number of permutations of the boys and girls in which the girls are not adjacent to each other like so $8!-6!\times3!$.

Then by the multiplication principle, we have $P(7,2)\times(8!-6!\times3!)$ such arrangements.

Please note that I do understand the solution where the boys are arranged first and the girls are placed between them afterwards. I just want to know what is wrong with mine and what I can do prevent such a mistake from happening again.

Comment: Your expression just counts the ways to do it so that the three girls aren't all together in a block.  You could still have, e.g. $GGBG\cdots$.

Comment: I see. Would using the inclusion-exclusion principle to calculate the permutations in which neither 2 nor 3 girls are together and then subtracting that from $8!$ work?

Comment: I prefer the stars and bars method.  You have gaps around and between the girls, as $\_G\_G\_G\_$.  You need to put at least one boy in each of  the two middle gaps, but then you have $3$ boys left to distribute to $4$ gaps without restriction.

Comment: I see. I don't have much experience with the stars and bars method. However, I do know some inclusion-exclusion, would that be applicable here? If yes, I'm thinking of finding $|AUB|$ where $A,B$ represent the events of two and three girls being together respectively and then subtracting that from $8!$.

Comment: Yes, you could do it by inclusion exclusion.  First subtract off the orders in which any specified pair of girls sit together.  Then add back the orders in which all three sit together.

Comment: Worth learning about [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) though.  Inclusion exclusion works here only because there are only three girls.  If there were $300$ girls then there would be simply too many cases to be (sensibly) handled by the method.  But Stars and Bars is more or less indifferent to the numbers involved.

Comment: Also, while applying inclusion-exclusion, why do you add back the orders in which all three sit together? Doesn't subtracting the orders in which any specified pair of girls sit together also get rid of the orders with three girls together.

Comment: Yes, but it gets rid of them more than once.  That's why you need inclusion exclusion (note the sign changes).  If you have the block $G_1G_2G_3$ then you removed it $2$ times...first when you took out the $G_1G_2$ pair and then again when you took out $G_2G_3$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I fully understand this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Arrange the seven boys in a row, which can be done in $7!$ ways.  Since boys must occupy both ends of the row, this creates six spaces in which the three girls can be placed.
$$B \square B \square B \square B \square B \square B \square B$$
To ensure that no two girls are adjacent, choose three of those six spaces in which to place a girl, which can be done in $\binom{6}{3}$ ways.  The three girls can be arranged in the selected spaces in $3!$ ways.  Hence, the number of admissible arrangements is 
$$7!\binom{6}{3}3!$$